# Extract tar.gz{some integer} in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract a file name with this format--> **filename.tar.gz10**

I have tried mutpile wayd but for all of them, I get the error that is unknow format. it works fine for files ends with **tar.gz00**. I tried to change the name but still does not work.

Here are what I have tried,

```
import tarfile
  
file = tarfile.open('filename.tar.gz10')

file.extractall('./extracted_path')
  
file.close()
```

Another way is,

```
shutil.unpack_archive('./filename.tar.gz10', './extracted_path', 'tar.gz17')
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This coule be because the archive was split into smaller chunks, on linux you could do so using the `split -b` command so one big file is actually multiple smaller ones now, and they are named like

```
file.tar.gz01
file.tar.gz02
file.tar.gz03
file.tar.gz04
etc...
```

you wont be able to decompress these file individually, so you have to concatenate them first into one file then decompress.

To verify whther it was split or not, run `file {filename}` and if does not recognize it as a gzip compressed archive then it is propably split (this is why you get unknown format error)

You can try to do the following:

```py
from glob import glob
import os
 
path = '/path/to/' # location of your files
list_of_files = glob(path + '*.tar.gz*') # list all gzip files
 
bash_command = 'gzip -dk filename.tar.gz' + ' '.join(list_of_files) # create bash command to concatenate the files
os.system(bash_command)
```

Comment: it returns 1. So all the files are in one directory and it does not concatenate the files.